# Webview android scroll to particular id on click

Tags: javascript, java, android, html, webview

I am working on android `webview`, the numbers will be listed from **1-100** if i click **55** the page have to scroll and go to the **55th** paragraph, after that I may able to scroll up or down, I found I can achieve it with javascript I tried something like

```
 content+="<div id="+i+">";
 i++;
 content += cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(VERSE_CONTENT));
 content+="</div>";
```

I have added an id for each paragraph

and on `onclick`

```
sample = dbhelper.getMonBookChap(bible, intent_bookid, intent_chapid);
sample = "<div style='line-height:150%;text-align: justify;'>" + sample + "</font></div>";
wv_Content.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
wv_Content.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
wv_Content.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptReceiver(this), "Android");
wv_Content.loadUrl("javascript:scrollToElement('" + intent_verseid + "')");
```

and I have created a `JavaScriptReceiver.java` class, I don't know where to place the javascript code on the project.

```
function scrollToElement(id) {
    var elem = document.getElementById(id);
    var x = 0;
    var y = 0;

    while (elem != null) {
        x += elem.offsetLeft;
        y += elem.offsetTop;
        elem = elem.offsetParent;
    }
    window.scrollTo(x, y);
}
```

Comment: The js function will be inside the html you are going to display on your webview.

Comment: sorry, since i am newbie to android i couldnt get you can you explain more @statosdotcom

Answer (score 2):

Add the javascript to the beginning of the content variable (your html content), in `<script>`  tags.

```
 String content ="<script>  
    function scrollToElement(id) {
        var elem = document.getElementById(id);
        var x = 0;
        var y = 0;

        while (elem != null) {
            x += elem.offsetLeft;
            y += elem.offsetTop;
            elem = elem.offsetParent;
        }
        window.scrollTo(x, y);
    }
    </script>";

   content += "<div id="+i+">";
     i++;
     content += cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(VERSE_CONTENT));
     content+="</div>";
```

One more suggestion, I would recommend handling all this in js, I mean click event and scrolling. Not calling

```
wv_Content.loadUrl("javascript:scrollToElement('" + intent_verseid + "')");
```

at all, just set some class or id to div, and set onclick from JS.